# Remove "/php/" subdirectory from URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've been trying to achieve the following rewrite/redirect on a website I'm building but I'm struggling and can't find the right answer online.

I want to rewrite

```
http://www.example.com/php/someFile.php
```

To:

```
example.com/someFile
```

I have managed to achieve most of the desired result with the following code in my .htaccess root file but I need help with removing the php subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove www from url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# redirect /file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]

# internally map /file to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  [L]
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it this way in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

# remove www from url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect /php/file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:php/)?([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R=301]

# internally map /file to /php/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/php/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ php/$1.php [L]
```

Make sure to test after clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove www from url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect /file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/php/file\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ file [R=301]
RewriteRule ^ php/file.php [L]
```

Comment: I've tried the answer and I'm now receiving the following message: 

Moved Permanently

The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 301 Moved Permanently error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The "here" hyperlink points towards the same URL.

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, ok, could you please try my edited rules once? Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Please do let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: I used your edited rules which produced the error message above. Is there anything else you suggest?

Comment: /@ConnorMcgrann, Could you please do let me know sample/example url which you are hitting here?

Comment: Unfortunately the domain I'm using is private as I'm working on it for a client, the domain is a .co.uk domain, does that give you enough to go on?

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, no, you need not to give actual url, give it like `http://localhost:80/test` etc like that so that I can understand it better.

Comment: The URL before the .htaccess will display as http://www.localhost:80/php/file.php

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, ok so any url like `http://localhost:80/file` OR `http://localhost:80/test` should be served by `php/file.php`? Also are you hitting url `http://localhost:80/file` in your browser?

Comment: Yes all of the files that will be displayed on the browser will be under the /php/file.php directory

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, ok, I have edited the rules now, could you please do check once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: I've tried your new rules but they don't seem to be changing the URL at all. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, ok let me re-iterate it: You are hitting url like `http://localhost:80/file` which should be served by `http://localhost:80/php/file.php`? So should it change URL in browser too? Do you want it to change to `http://lcoalhost:80/php/file.php`? Sorry its not clear.

Comment: The A href points towards ```http://localhost:80/php/file.php```, At that point I then want to remove the /php/ subdirectory and remove the php file extension to make the url display as ```http://localhost:80/file```

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, I am assuming that you are hitting url like `http://localhost:80/php/file.php` and you want to look on browser like `http://localhost:80/file` and should be served by php/file.php in backend, if this is the case and I understood correctly then please try my edited rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: The new edits now display the following error message ```Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.```

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, ok, could you please do let me know if my understanding in my previous comment is correct?

Comment: Yes your comments were completely correct.

Comment: @ConnorMcgrann, then my edited/current rules should work for you honestly.

Comment: I'll retry some of the settings and try to get it to work, thanks again for your help.